# How might one backup and restore a Microsoft Access database, using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

How might one backup and restore a Microsoft Access database, using VB.NET?

Answer (score 2):

Backing up and restoring a native Access database is simply a matter of copying the entire database file (.mdb for Access_2003 and earlier, .accdb for Access_2007 and later). You could use VB.NET for that, but any scripting language would work, even a simple Windows batch file that does something like

```
copy /Y d:\apps\databases\mydatabase.accdb z:\backups\databases\*.*
```